# Data Description for several Attributes in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, bokeh

Suppose i have two attributes 'Gender' and 'Short or Tall'

```
df = {'Gender': [Male, Male, Female, Male, Female, Male],
  'Short or Tall':[T, T, S, T, S, S]
  }
```

Now, How can i get a full Description for my data frame

ex: How Many Tall Males and Short Males and their percentage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `groupby.size`

```
data = {'Gender': ['Male', 'Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Female', 'Male'],
          'Short or Tall':['T', 'T', 'S', 'T','S', 'S']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data) # Construct a dataframe.
df = df.groupby(['Gender', 'Short or Tall']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)

print (df)

Short or Tall  S  T
Gender             
Female         2  0
Male           1  3
```

Comment: Good  One @Ahi .

Answer (score 1):

Using `crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(df.Gender,df['Short or Tall'])
Out[429]: 
Short or Tall  S  T
Gender             
Female         2  0
Male           1  3
```

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 using the accepted answer is constructor to create the df  :-)

Comment: Yes, I tried that, that is running fine but then your `crosstab` one is giving me an error saying `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'Gender'` not sure about it.